# Why does the XAML Grid not display all the panels correctly?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core, layout

I am learning WPF and XAML. I am experimenting with different Layouts so I put everything in a `<Grid>` with each cell having a different layout.

After I wrapped the `<StackPanel>` and the `<DockPanel>` in the `<Grid>`, it hid the `<StackPanel>` for some reason, when I specified for it to be in Row 1, Column 1. It also puts the `<DockPanel>` in the second row, when I specified for it to be in the first row. Why is the Grid placing and hiding everything so unusually?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Name="Button" Click="button_Click">Click me!</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <DockPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top">Dock = "Top"</TextBox>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">Dock = "Bottom"</TextBox>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left">Dock = "Left"</TextBox>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right">Dock = "Right"</TextBox>
        <TextBox Background="White">This TextBox "fills" the remaining space.</TextBox>
    </DockPanel>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Polygon Points="50, 100 200, 100 200, 200 300, 30" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" Fill="Yellow" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

[image: Window]

Comment: You've got your `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` property values set incorrect, that's why you see that behavior. They start at index `0` not `1`.

Comment: @Suresh Oh I didn't realize because it didn't say it in the docs but in their example code it does. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` values start at `0` not `1`.

In your XAML you set `Grid.Row` to `1` for both `StackPanel` and `DockPanel`. So, `Grid` is laying those two over each other. That's why you only see `DockPanel` not the `StackPanel`.

To get the desired output, you need to set `Grid.Row` to `0` for your `StackPanel`

Here is updated XAML with the correct values set for `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Name="Button">Click me!</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top">Dock = "Top"</TextBox>
            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">Dock = "Bottom"</TextBox>
            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left">Dock = "Left"</TextBox>
            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right">Dock = "Right"</TextBox>
            <TextBox Background="White">This TextBox "fills" the remaining space.</TextBox>
        </DockPanel>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Polygon Points="50, 100 200, 100 200, 200 300, 30" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" Fill="Yellow" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

You may want to refer to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=netcore-3.1) for more understanding on  Grid.